# Farewell, y'all

Tags: discussion

Dear fine gentlebeings of Ask Ubuntu and other hitchhikers of the internet,

**[DON'T PANIC (imagine this written in large, friendly letters).](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/219714-in-many-of-the-more-relaxed-civilizations-on-the-outer)**

It is with a heavy heart that after being a moderator for the last 7 years (and really, not doing much for the last ~4 of them) that it is only right to vacate my spot on the roster and allow for someone else who is actively using Ubuntu and an active member of this community to be involved.

Before I continue, I would like to make it clear that unlike [Seth](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18829/its-time-for-me-to-go), **I am not resigning because of the recent actions of Stack Exchange, Inc**. This has been something I have been thinking about since I changed jobs in March, and during conversations with the other moderators I realized that it was time.

So, without further fanfare, let's have a little trip down memory lane about where things were 7 years ago when I became a moderator:

- Ubuntu 12.10 was released
- The site had about 46,000 users (the site passed the 1,000,000 mark a few weeks ago - that's a lot different!!)
- We were getting [gold watch spam pretty much every day](https://askubuntu.com/election/2), and it was kind of a (sad) running joke (go to that page and Ctrl-F for "gold watch")
- We had a very small moderator team - when I joined there were 3 moderators, and we doubled the size with the election of 2012.

I don't really know how to end this, other than to say "Thank you" - I have really enjoyed my time as a moderator, and I believe that the current moderator team will continue to serve you well.

So long, and thanks for all the fish.

Answer (score 25):

Real life is like that. Thanks for all the work in those 7 years :)

Don't be a stranger though and drop in chat every so often.

You can have some cookies but the fish stays where it is. The fish is reserved for 200k+ rep users. With only 40.8k rep you just managed to get out of the newbie state so cookies. You can have 42 towels for the new journey you started. And some milk. But the fish stays.

> Ubuntu 12.10 was released

What a lousy release that was. Stupid secure boot got introduced. Amazon search results. The death of Unity 2D. Oh and web app integration.

Comment: Man I loved 12.10 though.. idk, one of my favorite releases.

Comment: 6.06 was way better :-D It had a Drake. A Dapper Drake. Can't beat a Drake

Comment: Drakes are definitely cool, but I still think fondly of 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) because that's when Ask Ubuntu showed up on the installer!